# Is this discontinuity proof finished?

Tags: continuity, solution-verification

> Show that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, defined with $f(x)=\begin{equation}
>     \begin{cases}
> \begin{aligned}
>       x-1,\text{for }x<1\\
>       1, \text{     for }x=1\\
>       x+1, \text{  for }x>1 
> \end{aligned}
>     \end{cases}\,
> \end{equation}$ is ***not*** continous on $x_0=1$.

I've done the following proof but I'm not sure if it's sufficient:

Take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Then:

$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x)-1|=\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
      |x-2|,\text{for }x<1\\
      0, \text{     for }x=1\\
      |x|, \text{  for }x>1 
\end{aligned}
    \end{cases}\,
\end{equation}\geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are working from the definition of continuity, or rather from its negation, and so you must prove:

> There exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ there exists $x$ such that $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $|f(x)-f(x_0)| \ge \epsilon$.

You've made a good start by choosing $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. But no, you're not done.

What you must still do is: let $\delta > 0$, and then find an appropriate value of $x$ (depending on $\delta$) and use it to prove that $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and that $|f(x)-f(x_0)| \ge \epsilon$.

With the formula you worked out for $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$, I suspect you can now easily find $x$.